# Commerce: how can I execute javascript after a product has been added to the cart?

Tags: commerce, hooks

I want to run Javscript once a product has been added to cart (with the script including product info).

The only thing I have tried is `hook_commerce_cart_product_add()` with `drupal_add_js()` but this doesn't seem to work. Ideally I would like it work like `drupal_set_message()`, so the script displays on the next page view.

I also need to get this working with removing products from the cart.

EDIT: Well I've discovered that doing the following actually works, but seems dodgy as hell, and would like to find a better way:

```
drupal_set_message("<script>alert('TEST');</script>");
```

Any ideas would be welcomed!

Comment: use a click function on the add to cart button div?

Comment: Are you using an AJAX add to cart module or are you using the standard add to cart functionality that refreshes the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should better use **Rules** here and the related events. The hook you mention ([hook_commerce_cart_product_add](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.api.php/function/hook_commerce_cart_product_add)) is a rules event hook.

```
Commerce Cart: After adding/removing a product to the cart
```

Then on the action add with php the js (`drupal_add_js()`) but if you simply want to **show a message** there is an action to do this easily.

```
System: Show a message on the site
```